# How can i set default skin in Libgdx?

Tags: graphics, libgdx, default, skin

I created a custom skin in my `Assets` class called `skin1`, then i write codes in my other class

```
TextButton button1 = new TextButton("Button1", Assets.skin1); 
TextButton button2 = new TextButton("Button2", Assets.skin1); 
TextButton button3 = new TextButton("Button3", Assets.skin1); 
...
```

and i always use `Assets.skin1` parameter in my all `TextButton` objects.
Is there any set method like **setDefaultSkinToMyGame(Assets.skin1)** for set my skin **only one times**?
Then i want to use only

```
TextButton button1 = new TextButton("Button1");
```

and it must use `Assets.skin1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `TextButton` with a customized constructor:

```
public class Skin1TextButton extends TextButton {
    public Skin1TextButton(String text) {
        super(text, Assets.skin1);
    }
}
```

Now your code is relieved from specifying the `Skin`:

```
TextButton button1 = new Skin1TextButton("Button1"); 
TextButton button2 = new Skin1TextButton("Button2"); 
TextButton button3 = new Skin1TextButton("Button3");
```